# How do you theme the node edit page?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

What filename do you use to theme the node edit page in Drupal 7?

Comment: I think this will help. It explains both the module and template.php solution: https://drupal.org/node/1092122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about theme()ing the page on which the node edit form is displayed, you would use `page--node--edit.tpl.php`.

More information on Drupal 7 Template Suggestions can be found [here](https://drupal.org/node/1089656).